# using setValue in Zend-Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I try to pass a value to an Zend-Form element. It shall be filled when the formclass is instantiated. Perhaps it is even the wrong idea?

What I gonna do:

I want to give a value to my formclass via my controller addAction:

```
$form = new PadForm(NULL, $test->UnitPartID);
```

Here is the constructor of my form class:

```
 public function __construct($name = null, $unitpartid)
```

Now I thought it must be easy to give the value to an element:

add.phtml

```
$UnitPartID= $form->get('UnitPartID');
$UnitPartID->setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
$UnitPartID->setAttribute('placeholder', 'UnitPartID');

$UnitPartID->setValue($this->unitpartid);
```

Unfortunately the form element doesn't get the value.

Where is the error? I think I'm quite close to the solution?? Any help appreciated.

Comment: are you sure `$this->unitpartid` is not empty when you do it ?

Comment: you are right I just echoed it. How can I do it properly?

Comment: why "setValue" and not "populateValues"? i mean $form->populateValues(['UnitPartID' => 5]);

Comment: I will try that, I used populate in Zend 1 and I thought it is deprecated in Version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a shame, because it is so easy in the end. But for beginners in Zend, it is sometimes hard to understand, where to do things properly. 
So I want to post the solution for others who have the same issues.

In my controller addaction I gave the form field a value, after instantiating the Form class.

```
$form->get('Formfield')->setValue(some variable);
```

I had the hole topic, because I was searching for a possibility to do it in the view. There I could give a value of course, but I couldn't fetch a variable. If somebody has still a suggestion for this possibility, please post. I answer my question because I now have one working solution.